# ef6 .net core with existing database

Tags: .net, .net-core, entity-framework-6

I am trying to use an ado.net entity data model in a 4.5 .net app referenced by a core 2.1 app. I looked at ef core, but the database has over 500 tables and I only need to access about 6 of them and a few stored procedures. It gives me errors in the core app when it executes code from ef Is there any way to get this to work? I have to use .net core for the Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus nuget.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot combine a full framework assembly (in your case a "4.5 .net app") and a .NET Core assembly. That will not work, regardless of what you use.

You could build a new Assembly with EF Core and .NET Core that references only what you need. That might be the better option anyway.

However, `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` seems to be available for .NET Standard. You may need to upgrade your framework version, but you should be able to use it with the full framework.